# VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest always returns 0 for yaw/pitch/roll

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to get the pitch / yaw / roll of a face in an image using the Vision framework but always get 0 for all values. Images should be very easy to process (mostly forward looking portraits).

I've successfully got these values by using Amazon Rekognition on them, so the images themselves aren't the issue. (I need to do a batch of about 70,000 so using rekogniton for them all will get expensive and slow.)

This is the request code:

```
let faceLandmarksRequest = VNDetectFaceRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: handleRectangles)

let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: cgImage!, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation.right ,options: [:])

do {
    try requestHandler.perform([faceLandmarksRequest])
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And here's the handler code:

```
func handleRectangles(request: VNRequest, errror: Error?) {

    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] else {
        fatalError("unexpected result type!")
    }

    for face in observations {

        print("\(face.yaw))") // always zero

    }
}
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: In your handler code, you pass the `guard let` statement but is your error (errror?) actually nil?

Comment: The guard statement doesn’t get triggered. The actual yaw and roll and pitch values are Zero as in the number, not nil or an error.

Comment: Yes I understand that but something isn’t working as intended and you are ignoring the error parameter of the completion handler. Surely it is worth checking? It wouldn’t be there otherwise.

Comment: Ah OK. I see what you mean now! I’ll check. It is getting the bounding box OK though.

Comment: The error is nil so it's not that either.

Answer (score 2):

Actually roll and yaw work, but for now they are very rough.
You always get zero because roll and yaw (as of 2019) are a discrete set of 6 or 7 values rather than a continuous range of values with exact orientation of the face.

Try a "more rotated" face.